# How to find a third monitor which will fit with existing ones?

Tags: multiple-monitors, comparison

So I currently have a setup which has two monitors.  Recently I have been thinking that this setup is less than ideal, because there is no primary monitor right in front of me for me to focus on, I end up choosing one of them arbitrarily (the right one seems to win most of the time) and then I get some pain from looking to one side most of the day.  So, I want to get a third monitor.  The problem is: I can't buy a third monitor which is the same dimensions as the two I have, because everything is widescreen nowadays.

The monitors I have right now are a pair of [Dell 2001FP](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/monitors/2001fp/EN/specs.htm)s.  This gives me a great resolution of 1600x1200, and I want to have optimally 1200 resolution in the vertical, so that it will match.  I'm fine with the new one being widescreen - in fact it makes sense to have a primary as widescreen to me and off to the sides have 4:3s.  The problem is that none of the specs online will tell me how *tall* the viewable area is.   I've found a [number of monitors](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010190020%201106209153&name=1920%20x%201200) with 1920x1200 resolution, but I don't know which size (diagonal) to get.

**How can I find out how tall physically a monitor will be so it matches with the ones I have?**

Comment: Can you post the panel size of the monitors you have and anything you're looking at?  It should be listed as a diagonal value, and make sure its only the panel size, not the bezel size (as bezels can be differently-sized but adjusted to be taller or shorter to match another monitor's panel).

Comment: My current panels (2001FP) is 16.1in by 12.1in, or at least that is what it says on the spec sheet.  I can measure more accurately when I get back to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the diagonal viewable length (of the existing 4:3 monitors), and you know the aspect ratio is 16:10 (for the new monitor you'd like to purchase), then this becomes a problem in math, i.e. solving a system of equations for a single unknown.  Or, try out the [TV Calculator](http://www.tvcalculator.com/) until you get something that works.

I played around with it, and it seems you'll need about a 23" (diagonal) 16:10 monitor.

Comment: 23" is ideal, unfortunately, most 23" monitors only offer 1680x1050.  It won't be perfect, but 24" monitors are 1920x1200, and should work better for you.

Comment: Agreed -- if finding a good 23" at 1920x1200 is difficult, then 24" is the next best.  There do exist such 23", but question is: with so little selection, are any of them any good?

Answer (score 0):

Take a tape measure and go visit your local computer screen store.